# How do I send automated emails in php?

Tags: php

Hey all, I have a form that I type a message in, then I click submit and it sends to all the users that are signed up for a messaging service. 
What I am trying to do is make it so that every day this form submits on its own without me having to press a button. I have been told that in linux you can create a script in cron, but my server is not running on linux, and I dont have access to my root directory. Thanks guys!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Are you using Windows? If so, you can schedule jobs using the Scheduler. You can set it up to call your php script at a certain time every day. [Here's more info.](http://support.microsoft.com/kb/308569)

Answer (score 3):

You can [schedule a task](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Task_Scheduler) on Windows, or you might even be interested in [CRONw](http://cronw.sourceforge.net/) - CRON for Windows.

Answer (score 1):

You can use a online cron service, which is basically a computer on the internet will connect to your site once a day and click the submit button for you. Here a [list of some of these services](http://www.onlinecronservices.com/)